# How to integrate twitter in unity3d?

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine

Hai friends,

I am new for unity3d.In my application i need to post score on twitter .but i dont know how to integrate twitter in unity3d application. please any one  give sample code or any suggestion.

Comment: if u have any doubts post your questions in stackoverflow.

Comment: it is not concern with pure programming issue, but I want to know the initial step about bubble shooter game, should I post it on Stack dear?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076096/cocos2d-bubble-shooting-game

Comment: I have posted the question, hopefully you will give me better idea, and scope, I would be thankful to you.

Comment: Prime31 studio sells a $60 package that does this. http://www.prime31.com/unity/ I do not know of any open-source packages that replicate for what you are asking.

Comment: I realize this question is very old, but [Lets Tweet in Unity](http://u3d.as/content/young-wook-yang/let-s-tweet-in-unity/1Dq) is a free package in the Unity Asset Store.