# Cocos2d Bubble Shooting Game

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have worked with cocos2d before, that was simple game with moving objects (CCSprite), but now I want to make a bubbleshooter game , 
Can anyone briefly give me idea how it will work, the flow of game and what should I use, like as I think there will be on layer, and CCSprite over it, but still not clear idea in mind

I would be thankful if someone will describe the whole flow, and classes, more briefly I will specify some major points

1. What are bubbles used in game? (Image with CCSprites or something else)
2. How would I know the direction of shooting.
3. How would I know the collision is occured, and other balloons of same color connect to hitting balloon will also be vanished.

I would be thankful if someone provide the related task tutorials or source codes, so that I would get better idea about it.

Comment: @james, thanks for editing , but can you please guide me , I am not new to cocos2d, but yet confused about it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Bubbles are sprite Images.
2. Read this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/692/rotating-turrets it gives how to find the direction of Touch position.
3. collision detection as usual.In scheduler method find if the Moving ball is collide with other ball.

   ```
    -(void)checkCollision
   {
      for(CCSprite *ball In ballArray)
    {
       if(CGRectIntersectRect([ball boundingBox],[movingBall boundingBox]))
        {

            CCLOG(@"collision Occurs");

             }
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Banu have you seen the collision occures when same color of ball touches each other, how to do that, I think using tag property, but yet these ball arrangement confusing me?

Comment: i am also getting ball arrangement problem

Comment: Still you are developing the shooter game ?

Comment: No shooter game stopped some resons.